# I want to compute the total revenue per device on the last 7 days

Tags: sql, apache-superset, druid

I want to compute the sum(revenue) per device on the last 7 days .I am using database sql druid
and tool is apache superset.

Comment: Can you please provide some sample rows of your data so we can better help you?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your table contains columns `__time`, `device` and `revenue`.

I think this should do it:

```
SELECT device, SUM(revenue) 
FROM your_table
WHERE __time >= TIME_SHIFT(TIME_FLOOR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'P1D'),'P1D', -7)
GROUP BY 1
```

- `TIME_FLOOR` truncates CURRENT_TIMESTAMP to the beginning of the day.
- `TIME_SHIFT` moves the date 7 days back